# How to hide change owner button next to the owner field in Classic?

Tags: community, standard-field

I want to hide the [change] on field owner in salesforce classic, the owner field is standard field with  Lookup(User,Group), is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i remember that is not possible.

A workaround could be the following. Create a custom Field :

- Name: Record Owner
- API: Record_Owner__c
- Type: Formula
- Return Type: Text
- Formula: HYPERLINK("/" & OwnerId , Owner.FirstName &" "&
  Owner.LastName , '_self')

Then swap out the standard owner field, for the custom formula on the necessary PageLayout(s).

Note: This will only work, if the Owner is a User, not a Queue. If you have a queue as an owner, you'll have to modify it.